# Lollipop 5.1 recent application type tab in ios

Tags: ios

I want to develop `lollipop 5.1` recent application typed view in my app.
I tried it using third party application but it's still not done
please help.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third party library [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). 
Use this it would help you.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

These are few links for third party controls which provide card view like android recent. for reference

1) [YFCardTransitions](https://github.com/yuriferretti/YFCardTransitions)

2) [MTCardLayout](https://github.com/minhntran/MTCardLayout)